# "Недавние приложения" в Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Есть кнопка. Нужно при её нажатии открыть "недавние приложения". Как? Intent, думаю?

Answer (score 1):

Это [невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344738/how-do-i-launch-the-recent-apps-menu-in-android)

Comment: При том что Pie Control (и первая, и вторая) БЕЗ ROOT это делает. Мне нужен любой (ROOT/unROOT) способ.
А mx player ещё и кнопку HOME благополучно может блокировать.

Comment: Или. Качаем Simple Control, открываем, даем права в спец.возможностях. Забираем их. Как видно, всё работает. Значит можно!

Comment: @MoNTE48, можете попробовать вот [это](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: А можно пример, как "ЭТО" на кнопку повесить?

Comment: @MoNTE48, системный список вы не вызовете, но можете получить список недавних приложений, как я писал комментом раньше. Сейчас код написать не могу, но алгоритм примерно таков: по нажатию на кнопку получаем список недавних приложений, парсим его (вытягиваем иконки, названия и всё остальное нужное), потом делаем лэйаут, на него кладём иконки с надписями, ставим на них слушатели нажатий (по нажатию запустить (интент можно получить при парсинге) выбранное приложение) и показываем пользователю.

Comment: Хотите сказать что в Pie Control и Simple Control так? И как они тогда получают скрин окна/миниатюры?

Comment: @MoNTE48, хотите, чтоб было как в Pie Control/Simple Control - декомпилируйте и смотрите исходники там. Изначально вопрос был "как открыть недавние приложения", я вам ответил, что это невозможно и предложил альтернативу.

Answer (score 0):

С Эмулировать нажатие аппаратной кнопки меню